# Algebra, restriction equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Having 3 known positive variables (Z1,Z2,Z3) such that:

$$Z_1 = A+B+C+D+E$$
$$Z_2 = A+B+F-G$$
$$Z_3 = A-B-D+G$$

I want to obtain possible solutions (distributions) for {A,B,C...G} such that A,B,C... are all positive

I actually want to know a general way to do this, since my real problem involves more than 100 'letters' and tens of equations.

Is there anyway to do that? or any field that studies this?

Comment: You want to express the variables through $$Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$$?

Comment: It can be as a function fo Z1,Z2,Z3